# supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow returns UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait but my viewcontroller show in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation

I am handling all the orientations in the `appdelegate.m` file. `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` for some of my view controllers and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` for one viewcontroller.

When I move from a landscape viewcontroller to the viewcontroller I want to portrait `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` but my view controller appears in landscape.

Please help me I've been stuck for a long time. Testing on iPhone 6, iOS 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say view `A` is one of the landscape views of your app and `B` is the intended portrait view. Now, when the device is initially held in portrait on A and B is then accessed, the view doesn't change the orientation to portrait (since the device was already in portrait).

I'd suggest 'tell' system that B is initially in landscape while preparing the segue and then in your `viewDidLoad` for B's view controller, change the orientation to portrait.

This way, no matter what the previous view's orientation, B will always open in portrait when it loads.

Use the following code to change the orientation. In case you are using segue use this code in

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

The orientation here should be opposite of the desired orientation in the next view controller.